# Angular HTTP Param double quotes

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have a request call with method using **$http.get** angular.

```
return this.http.get(url+ `/pgb`, { params: {
      page: page.toString(),
      size: perPage.toString(),
      q: `productName=="${productName}"`
    }}
```

I expected request to be `http://url/pgb?page=1&size=10&q=productName=="macbook"`

but I got `http://url/pgb?page=1&size=10&q=productName==%22macbook%22`

I've been trying to use `encodeURIComponent` and etc but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
q: `productName=="${productName}"`
```

to

```
q: `productName==${productName}`
```

and try again Hope this helps. you don't need double quotes with URL params.
Thanks,

Comment: I've try remove double quotes and it's not working, when I'm using vue js and axios it's work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me like using double equal (==) and quotes in a url is a horrible idea.

If you have control over the server, can you simply add another parameter?

```
size: perPage.toString(),
productName: productName
```

otherwise, maybe simply create the string yourself?

```
var url = 'http://url/pgb?page=1&size=10&q=productName=="macbook"';
return this.http.get(url)
```